# Purchase multiple products with react-native-iap

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, react-native-iap

I have used react-native-iap to implement in-app purchases in my ios app. The purchases are working fine but I have a cart feature in my app. I want to be able to purchase multiple products at the same time. Is this possible? Is there any alternative way in which I can handle this feature?

Comment: You can write code to let the user build a list of things they want to purchase but you need to submit each item purchase to storekit individually and the user will be prompted to approve each purchase individually